# Python requests send multiple cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

How would you go about sending multiple cookies with python requests

the documentation only gives

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/cookies'
cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
r.text
```

Here is what i have tried currently

```
url = 'http://192.168.0.57/dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=include.php'
cookies = dict(cookies_are=options.cookie)
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

when i run my script with

```
--cookie="security=Low; PHPSESSID=4edca0525666fbbe319f50ce3630b4a9"
```

the security cookie is not recognised but the PHPSESID is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cookies` parameter is a dict where the key is cookie name and the value is cookie value. So while your cookie-input is cookie string you have two ways to use it with `requests`:

1) parse cookie string and make the dict from it like the following:

```
import requests
from Cookie import SimpleCookie

cookie_string = options.cookie
cookie = SimpleCookie(cookie_string)
cookie_dict = {k: v.value for k, v in cookie.iteritems()}
requests.get(url, cookies=cookie_dict)
```

2) simply set it as `Cookie` header:

```
import requests
from Cookie import SimpleCookie

cookie_string = options.cookie
headers = {'Cookie': cookie_string}
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I am getting *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cookie'
* did *pip install cookies* but it didn't helped. any help on this?