# Send multiple cookies in python

Tags: python, python-requests

How do I send multiple cookies in python?.

Currently I send a single cookie value as below:

```
cookies ={'auth':123456789}
res = requests.get("http://www.example.com/",cookies=cookies)
```

I need to send a cookie like below:

```
cookies ={'auth':123456789,'auth2':abcde}
    res = requests.get("http://www.example.com/",cookies=cookies)
```

I get SyntaxError for this.

Can anyone suggest alternative way for this?

Comment: Can you not just do `cookies ={'auth':123456789, 'cookie2' : 2}` etc.?

Comment: I tried it ... IT didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests send multiple cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801680/python-requests-send-multiple-cookies)

Comment: @musefan I checked the link. Can you please modify my above code?

Comment: What does the "syntax error" say?

Comment: @musefan Thanks for the solution. Actually there was an encoding issue with the cookie value auth!...