# how to save cookies from puppeteer and use the cookies to make request in python?

Tags: python, node.js, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
// add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())


puppeteer.launch({ headless: true,ignoreHTTPSErrors:true, args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--proxy-server=51.158.111.242:8811' ] }).then(async browser => {


console.log('Running tests..')

const page = await browser.newPage()

await page.goto('https://google.com/')

const cookies = await page.cookies();

console.log(cookies);

await fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2));

await page.screenshot({ path: 'testresult.png', fullPage: true })

await browser.close()

})
```

after saving the cookies into the file, it saves multiple cookies dictionary in file

[
  {
    "name": "_gat",
    "value": "1",
    "domain": "www.google.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1582024891,
    "size": 5,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false
  },
  {
    "name": "_gid",
    "value": "GA1.2.1936512649.1582024831",
    "domain": "www.google.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1582111231,
    "size": 31,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false
  },
  {
    "name": "_ga",
    "value": "GA1.2.1830413277.1582024831",
    "domain": "www.google.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1645096831,
    "size": 30,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false
  },
  {
    "name": "__cfduid",
    "value": "d9ccc472957afbae818db60dff47cc5e01582024830",
    "domain": "www.google.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1584616830.613503,
    "size": 51,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "sameSite": "Lax"
  }
]

I am not able to decide which one should use for making a request in the python-requests module?

Comment: why not just send all of them?

Comment: the python-requests library doesn't support the list as cookies.

Comment: you don't need to pass the list, that list is basically equivalent of dict of key values. python's requests supports multiple cookies key values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801680/python-requests-send-multiple-cookies

Comment: also each key value plays a different role, and it's not your job to determine which cookies are useful/related to the functionality you want, websites define that. you should just behave like a browser and send any cookie in the cookie jar that match the domain/path and flags.

Comment: yes, you are right I got the answer, you saying it right passing all cookies using list is working correctly right now.

Comment: @abhaykumar would you mind how you converted the puppeteer cookies to a list for requests? I'm not able to directly use the saved puppeteer cookies